# fat free crm installation mysql error

Tags: mysql, crm

I ma trying to install fat free crm on windows using these instructions http://guides.fatfreecrm.com/Setup-Microsoft-Windows.html

I am on the part where we install mysql2 lib and libmysql.dll

The command  "gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql2 -v 0.2.7 -- with-mysql-dir=X: --with-mysql-lib=X:\bin --with-mysql-include=X:\include"  fails and error comes  "Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.".I fixed this part my changing the version of mysql in the command to 0.3.11.Now the last step says to copy libmysql.dll but I cant find that file in the specified directory.

Comment: "and some error comes" probably isn't enough information for people to help you.

Comment: fixed.provided the error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's of interest, Bitnami has recently published a one-click installer for FFCRM. See https://bitnami.com/stack/fat-free-crm I'll also update the FFCRM docs to note this.